# Salesforce Tests for Org

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

**Should every APEX class have its own test class?**

Currently dealing with tests in an org where 80% of APEX tests are under one test class which does not seem to be the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that yes indeed, having all the org's tests in one single class is not really something recommended. Some of the drawbacks that I see:

- Big classes increase dependency meaning that is more likely that several developers work on the same class, which increases complexity
- When one big class contains all the test methods it is harder to functionally "scope" your tests. When an independent class contains test methods for a certain class, it is easier to understand what is trying to be tested and to further extend the class coherently
- By using different classes you can make better use of the @testSetup annotation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm) because only one method per class can be annotated with the @testSetup annotation

Those are some of the reasons (among others for sure) why you would prefer to split your test methods in different classes.

Comment: Thanks for the link, would it be best to write a separate test class for each Apex class/trigger? I wasn't sure if this would be overkill or not.

Comment: I don't think that it is an overkill, I think it is a good way to organize the tests. In all the projects that I've been working on, that was the guideline that was being followed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no one answer that suit all situation for this question. It will be on case by case basis.

Since you only have 1 Test Class for your Org. I believe your code base is not that big yet and it is very good time to start introduce Design Pattern that suitable for your use case and refactor that code.

Comment: thanks for the response! Is there a specific Design Pattern that is most suitable for salesforce?  I wasn't sure if creating a separate test class for each APEX class/Trigger was the best solution.